# MYSQLI insert other language problam

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am  using other language to save that in the  phpmyadmin, but it's working like that :

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO list (title,content) 
VALUES ('other language TITLE', 'other language CONTENT ')");
```

and it's showing in phpmyadmin like that :

> áƒ•áƒáƒšáƒ”áƒ áƒ˜ áƒ’áƒ”áƒšáƒ‘áƒáƒ®áƒ˜áƒáƒœáƒ

any solutions please?

Comment: UFT-8 encoding needs to be on as a minimum.  You need to understand Unicode well.

Comment: Please start reading and learning about character encoding in the various parts of your setup. We cannot magically guess your setup or your input and this question-answer-style is not suited to give you an in-depth explanation about the topic. There are existing introductions on the internet. Please read them.

Comment: Have you tried Collation in PhpMyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I did

```
 mysqli_query($con , "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', 
  character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', 
  character_set_server = 'utf8'");
```

IT WORKED

Comment: just use mysqli_set_charset("utf8")

Answer (score 0):

it's a charset problem. when you create table (or db) set collation to utf8_general_ci. if the problem is not about table, maybe there's wrong charset in your phpmyadmin or in browser(charset shoudl be set to utf8)

Comment: hi Heavymetal91 ,  thanks for your comment, I fixed database it's getting other language, but when I push it to the page from database, it's giving me "????????" those,  I use <meta charset="utf-8"> in html, but it's still giving me question marks, if I go <p>სდსდასდ</> it's giving me correct spelling, what may be a problam?

Comment: set utf-8 without-BOM encode for current file. check the database, is there also qustion marks? are you sure that you stored data correctly(not with ???) tu arada magis dedac movtyan, mtavaria chven viyot kargad :D

Comment: :D ok, i fixed actually $conn->set_charset('utf8');   aman gaaswora....

Comment: tu ici shen, scripti maqvs dawerili rom ragac informacia gaparsos da bazashi waigos, amistvis mchirdeba ro php faili cmd dan gavushva, localze chveulebrivad mushaobs : php index.php    ,  serverze ro avtvirte cmd dan rogor gavushva es scrpti?

Comment: ssh dostupi gaq? serverze savaraudod linuksi geqneba terminalidan shegzidzlia gaushva, mgoni php cli(command line interface) unda daayeno, sheidzleba amis gareshec qnas

Comment: ssh ar maq wvdp,a. xo ra eg pontia vichalicheb